# What is wrong with using scanf with a pointer without initializing?

Tags: c, scanf

scanf takes a pointer argument.. Why cant we pass a pointer variable?

```
int* x;
scanf("%d", x);
printf("%d", *x);
```

This does not give output.. Why? What is wrong?

Comment: Please read a beginner-level C book. To begin with, you need to initialize the variable...

Comment: Thank you... A pointer must have a value first...Now it works.. int a = 0;
    int* x = &a;
scanf("%d", x);
printf("%d", *x);

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format specifier to `scanf` expects a pointer to an `int`, i.e. a `int *`, which is what you are passing.  So you're calling the function correctly.

Where you went wrong is that the pointer `x` was never initialized and therefore doesn't point anywhere.  `scanf` then attempts to read this unitialized value as an address and subsequently read what is at that bogus address.  Reading an uninitialized value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make `x` point somewhere, either by assigning it the address of an `int` variable or by using `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory.

```
int a;
int *x = &a;
```

Or:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
```